# Passing array variable from event handler class to controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, event-handling, laravel-5, listener

I created event handler class in

```
   App\Events\Roomallocwithproperties(Event file)
   App\Handlers\Events\Allocofroomprop(Handler file)
```

In laravel 5,I Passed two variable from Controller and get that variable with the help of constructor inside Event file, as

```
  public function__construct($a,$b) {
       $this->a=$a;
         $this->b=$b;
                      }
```

This value I accessed in Handler file inside handl function such as

```
public function handle(Roomallocwithproperties $event)
 {
 $c= $event->a + $event->b;

 return $c;
 }
```

In the Eventservice provider file

```
protected $listen = [
    'event.name' => [
        'EventListener',
    ],
    'App\Events\Roomallocwithproperties'=>[
        'App\Handlers\Events\Allocofroomprop', 

        ],
];
```

And I fire the Events from Controller such as

```
       $result= Event::fire(new Roomallocwithproperties($val1,$val2));

       dd($result);
```

My problem is that I want to return the value $c to again my controller. The reason I use event is I fired the event from foreach every iteration,And again return the value inside it.
**How to return the variable $c to controller function , How to receive the value inside that controller function !**
Thanks for all replies !

Comment: Why would you want to pass it to controller? No code firing events should care about listeners that listen for those events.

Comment: In my controller function , inside foreachloop if condition is checked, if that condition is true, event is fired and from that event array value get collected, that value I want inside the executing foreach in the same iteration ! So I use events to fire !   Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

What you need is not the access to listeners. What you need are responses from the listeners.

**Event::fire()** method returns array of listeners responses. So whatever listener's **handle()** method returned will be in that array. Therefore your listeners need to just return whatever you want to collect from the **handle()** method.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. If Listener is to provide any kind of feedback, then it needs to do it by returning the value from handle method. If you post your code or explain what you really want to achieve I might be able to help, but at the moment I have no clue what you need.

Comment: In the provider you just list listeners for different events. You need to return value from the listener's handle method. "return $event->a + $event->b;" and then dd() the results of Event::fire() method in your controller and you should see the data returned

Comment: But what does not work? Are the event listeners called? What do you get returned from fire()?

Comment: I got returned empty array, Listners handle method also called, I checked by remove return and var_dump the ` var_dump($event->a + $event->b) ` it inside handler's method. In controler ` $res= Event::fire(); ` and print the result ` dd($res); `. Finally it returned empty array. Thanks for reply

Comment: Could you update the question with current code? I just tested it and got the response in the return value from Event::fire(). As long as you're not returning false from the handler it should work. What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Now I updated my current code that how I fire events with parameters and dd the return value. Thanks for considering my question !

Comment: Your handle() method still does not return anything

Comment: Oh sorry , I forget to updated in question, but I in my code I put return statement. still I get empty array !

Comment: I'm trying this out and it works... Did you do dd() in the handler to confirm it is run? Are there any other listeners for this event?

Comment: Yes , I checked with dd(), and var_dump(), It works in Listner's handle method, and also I don't have no other listners too for this event, But your information was really helpful and its correct, the problem is in my side. I check it and post ! Thank you very much for your help !